# Using pandas to check if values in one table are present in another table

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Python tables, *visitors* and *orders*. *visitors* has more rows than *orders*, because not every visitor ends up making a purchase.

I want to return a new table called *non orders* that basically contains IDs that are present in *visitors* but not in *orders*.

Any suggestions on how to implement this using pandas in Python?

Comment: You should provide the code that you have attempted to satisfy this with, and the error you encountered if any.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd    
visitors = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
orders = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1]})
nonorders=visitors.loc[~visitors.id.isin(orders.id),]

Out[57]: 
   id
2   2
3   3
4   4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in NumPy (using the same data as Wen):

```
np.setdiff1d(visitors,orders)
#array([2, 3, 4])
```

The same is possibly, but somewhat more cumbersome, in pure Pandas:

```
visitors.set_index('id').index.difference(orders.set_index('id').index)
#Int64Index([2, 3, 4], dtype='int64', name='id')
```